# How do I repeat one string to match the length of another string?

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I am trying to repeat the string "k" to match the length of "text" without going over the length. So it would output "treetreetreetreetreet" and not "treetreetreetreetreetree". I really dont know where to start other than just outputing more characters than needed.

```
PROGRAM test

  IMPLICIT NONE

  CHARACTER*30 :: text, k
  INTEGER :: times

  text = 'hello my name is anon'
  k = 'tree'
  times = (LEN_TRIM(text)/LEN_TRIM(k)) + 1

  WRITE(*,*) REPEAT(k,times)

END PROGRAM test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your sample program as-is doesn't produce `treetreetreetreetreetree` as you expect, it actually produces `tree                          tree                          tree   ...`. When you pass the string `k` to `REPEAT`, the spaces after `tree` also get repeated. You should trim the string before repeating it, such as `REPEAT(trim(k),times)`.

There are several ways to solve your main problem - I recommend using what you have so far but reducing the final result to the length you want - in this case `LEN_TRIM(text)`. A good way to do this is to store the output of `REPEAT` in a temporary variable and output only a subset of this final string.

With both of these modifications and some other cleanup, your code looks like:

```
program main
   implicit none
   character(len=30) :: text, k, str
   integer :: times

   text = 'hello my name is anon'
   k = 'tree'
   times = (LEN_TRIM(text)/LEN_TRIM(k)) + 1     ! -- Note integer division

   str = REPEAT(trim(k),times)

   write(*,*) str(1:LEN_TRIM(text))
end program main
```

which gives the desired output

```
> gfortran main.f90 && ./a.out
 treetreetreetreetreet
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, and spotting the other problem.